# AngularJS Service not displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im simply grabbing my Github information using Github's API. When I log my http request, it displays the right information.. Im not sure why it's not displaying on the page. I'm not getting any errors. (The partial is displaying, just not the requested data)

**Service**:

```
myApp.factory('githubApi', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        //Declaring a promise that will or will not return a users github information.
        return {
            async: function() {
                return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/joshspears3');
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

**Controller**:

```
myApp.controller('githubCtrl', [ 'githubApi', '$scope',
    function(githubApi, $scope){
        $scope.data = githubApi.async();
    }
]);
```

**Directive**:

```
myApp.directive('githubRequest', [
    function() {
        return {
            scope: {},
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: 'githubCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'public/views/partials/github-request.html'
        }
    }
]);
```

**github-request.html** (partial):

```
<p class="component-example-header">Creating a service. Grabbing information based on the github API.</p>
<div>
    Making a $http request to grab my personal Github information.
    <p>Avatar:</p>
    <img width="20%"src="{{data.avatar_url}}" alt="" />
    <p>Username: {{data.login}}</p>
    <p>Followers: {{data.followers}}, Following: {{data.following}}</p>
</div>
```

**Index.html**:

```
  <div>
     <global-header></global-header>
     <div ui-view></div>
     <github-request></github-request>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't used a promise here. Change your **async** function to:

```
return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/joshspears3').success(function(response) {
    return response.data
});
```

and your **controller** to:

```
function(githubApi, $scope){
    githubApi.async().then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: make sure you added the promise dependency into the code [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)